# System.Windows.Media.Color to Java int

Tags: java, c#, colors

I'm need some way to convert a System.Windows.Media.Color to a Java int with the following format: `0x00RRGGBB` in C#. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Go for it. I'm not clear what your question is though...are you running into problems implementing your idea? What are those problems?

Comment: Java gives you `new Color(r, g, b, a).getRGB();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Windows.Media.Color has a property for Alpha, Red, Green and Blue.

They're all of the type "byte" (value of 0-255).

You can mash all 4 of those properties into a single unsigned 32-bit integer using some simple bit-wise operations:

```
public uint ConvertColorToUInt(Color color)
{
    uint value = (color.A << 24) | (color.R << 16) | (color.G << 8) | color.B;
    return value;
}
```

or if it needs to be a string:

```
public string ConvertColorToJavaString(Color color)
{
    uint value = (color.A << 24) | (color.R << 16) | (color.G << 8) | color.B;
    var javaString = string.Format("0x{0}", value.ToString("X2"))
    return javaString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed, apologies if the question wasn't clearly defined.

Comment: No problem. Not sure why your question got marked off-topic or whatever. It seemed clear enough to me. Oh well.